# How to align ul tag content in center

Tags: css, html-lists, centering

I had been trying to align content of `#refer`'s `ul` content in the center of the screen using CSS.

```
<div id="refer" style="border:1px solid red">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#" class="circlelink">One</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#" class="circlelink">Two</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#" class="circlelink">Three</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>



.circlelink {
    display:block;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    border-radius:50px;
    font-size:20px;
    color:#fff;
    line-height:100px;
    text-align:center;
    text-decoration:none;
    background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #719ECE, #719FCE);
}

.circlelink:hover {
    text-decoration:none;
    background:#719ECE;
    box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.05, 1.07);
    -moz-transform: scale(1.05, 1.07);
}

#refer {
    position:absolute;
    top:20%;
    width:100%;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}

#refer ul {
    clear:both;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#refer ul li {
    display:block;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    height: auto;
    width: 200px;
    padding: 0;
    margin-left: 10px;
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ptMwH/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This worked for me in your fiddle:

```
* {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
#refer {
    margin:20% 0 0;
    width:100%;
    /*
    position:absolute;
    top:20%;
    width:100%;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    */
}
#refer ul {
    text-align:center;
    /*
    clear:both;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    */
}
#refer ul li {
    display:inline-block;
    position: relative;
    /* float: left; */
    height: auto;
    width: 100px;
    padding: 0;
    margin:0 50px;
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    border:#0f0 solid 1px;
}
.circlelink {
    display:block;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    border-radius:50px;
    font-size:20px;
    color:#fff;
    line-height:100px;
    text-align:center;
    text-decoration:none;
    background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #719ECE, #719FCE);
}
.circlelink:hover {
    text-decoration:none;
    background:#719ECE;
    box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.05, 1.07);
    -moz-transform: scale(1.05, 1.07);
}
```

Comment: This one made my day !!! I had **-webkit-margin-before: 1em** at rhis css element and it wasn't working! Thanks !!!

Answer (score 3):

code : [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ptMwH/2/)

All you have to do is :

1. Add `text-align:center;` into `#refer ul`
2. Change `display:block;` into `display:inline-block;` in `#refer ul li`
3. Remove `float:left;` from `#refer ul li`

Additionally, make sure the `#refer ul` provide `min-width` that provide required width for all circle to make sure it's not collapsed if browser window too small.

Additionally, it is better if you remove the `width` from your `#refer ul li`. Let the content `<a>` specify the width

Comment: Great answer, i can use for my problem, and more !

Answer (score 0):

[Here it is](http://jsfiddle.net/cha3W/)

```
.circlelink {

    display:block;

    width:100px;

    height:100px;

    border-radius:50px;

    font-size:20px;

    color:#fff;

    line-height:100px;

    text-align:center;

    text-decoration:none;

    background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #719ECE, #719FCE);

}

.circlelink:hover {

    text-decoration:none;

    background:#719ECE;

    box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);

    -webkit-transform: scale(1.05, 1.07);

    -moz-transform: scale(1.05, 1.07);

}

#refer {

    position:absolute;

    top:20%;

    width:100%;

    margin-left:auto;

    margin-right:auto;
    text-align:center;
}

#refer ul {

    clear:both;

    margin: 0;

    padding: 0;

}

#refer ul li {

    display:inline-block;

    position: relative;

    height: auto;

    width: 200px;

    padding: 0;

    margin-left: 10px;

    list-style: none;

    text-align: center;

    white-space: nowrap;

}
```

Comment: Thank you for replying, But yet the content is not in completely center.  Also it is using >100% width in web page. Can you please find the bug out?

Comment: remove width from #refer ul li

Answer (score 0):

wrapping your **ul** with a **div** will help

http://jsfiddle.net/ptMwH/11/ here check this

```
<div id="refer" style="border:1px solid red">
    <div class="wrapper">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#" class="circlelink">One</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#" class="circlelink">Two</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#" class="circlelink">Three</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```